# Get list of tables with column value as a condition

Tags: sql

I have  need to get list of tables  which  have a column locn with value 'cba' from  differnet schemas

EX :

```
select table_name where all_tab_columns where column_name='locn';
```

--- getting list of tables
     now i need to get  list of tables  where locn column having value as 'cba'

Please advice

Comment: Please the tag the _RDBMS_ ? or try using `select * from information_schema.tables` or this `select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns` then add the column_name or table_name that you want!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
        *
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C
WHERE
    COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%xxxxx%'
```

Replace xxxx with the column name or partial name.

This will tell you everything.

Answer (score 0):

If you require only table and columns then use

```
Select  object_name(c.object_id) 'Table',c.name,ROW_NUMBER() over(order by c.name) 'R'      into #temp
from    sys.tables t 
join    sys.columns c 
on      c.object_id = t.object_id 
where   c.name like '%col%'
```

If you require even data also then use the following link

```
http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/c0c57332-8624-48c0-b4c3-5b31fe641c58
```